# I want to trigger elements in my function one after another and not all at the same time by clicking the same button

Tags: reactjs, onclick

SO I am doing a little geography quiz and I need some help. I have created a Json file with different countries (image of it, population, area). When I click "Next", there will only be the image of the country. After that, I want to give more hints of that country by clicking the "Next Hint" button. My goal is now, that I only want to show one hint at the time (first area, then population) by clicking the "Next Hint" button. Right now, it shows all of them at the same time.

```
[
    {
       "id": 1,
       "image": "countries/pics/Deutschland.jpg",
       "area": "357,592 km²",
       "population": "84,270,625"

    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "image": "countries/pics/Frankreich.jpg",
        "area": "632,733 km²",
        "population": "68.042.591"  
    },
    {
        
    }

]

import {useState} from "react";
import country from "../Countries.json"

function Geography() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [area, setArea] = useState();
  const [population, setPopulation] = useState();
  const [countryList, setCountryList] = useState(country);

  const handleStart = () => {
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * country.length);
      setImage(countryList[random].image);
      setArea(countryList[random].area);
      setPopulation(countryList[random].population);
      const areaSolution = document.getElementById("area");
      areaSolution.innerHTML = "";
      const populationSolution = document.getElementById("population");
      populationSolution.innerHTML = "";
  }

  const handleHint = () => {
    const areaSolution = document.getElementById("area");
    areaSolution.innerHTML = area;
    populationHint();
}

const populationHint = () => {
  const populationSolution = document.getElementById("population");
  populationSolution.innerHTML = population;
}


  return (
    <div className='geo'>
      <h1>Guess the Country</h1>
        <div className='button'>
            <button className='button__start' onClick={handleStart}>Next</button>
            <button className='button__start' onClick={handleHint}>Next Hint</button>
        </div>
        <div className='pic'>
        <img src={image} />
        <h1 id='area'></h1>
        <h1 id='population'></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` should never be used in react like this. Its good for vanillaJS, but a single re-render can blow all of it away.

React is constantly writing and re-writing to the DOM. If it isn't aware of change through the JSX, it will be deleted and forgotten.

```
const [areaHint,setAreaHint] = useState('');
const [populationHint,setPopulationHint] = useState('');
...
  const handleHint = () => {
    setAreaHint(area);
    setPopulationHint('');
}

const populationHint = () => {
  setPopulationHint(population);
  setAreaHint('');
}
...
        <h1 id='area'>{areaHint}</h1>
        <h1 id='population'>{populationHint}</h1>
```